# Dividing list elements according to extra value in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list like below:

```
[
  {"name": "foo", "value": 50},
  {"name": "bar", "value": 10},
  {"name": "baz", "value": 100},
  {"name": "qux", "value": 30}
]
```

And I need to devide the list into N lists. The sums of the `value` of each element in the lists should be as close as possible.

For example, if dividing the list above with `N = 2`, the result should be:

```
[
  [
    {"name": "foo", "value": 50},
    {"name": "qux", "value": 30}
  ],
  [
    {"name": "bar", "value": 10},
    {"name": "baz", "value": 100}
  ]
]
```

Because the sums of their values are `80` and `110`, which is the closest.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to solve the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), or rather, [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning).

Comment: For an algorithm, see [this thread on code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/273970/greedy-number-partitioning-algorithm).  Also, the closest solution should be `[10, 30, 50]` and `[100]`, unless when you specified `N = 2` where each list must have 2 elements (though by the wording of "into N lists" negates this intention).